# What code do I enter to fix my radio on a Mitsubishi Eclipse?

Tags: audio, security

I had to replace my battery a few months ago. After I started my car back up I noticed that my radio wanted me to enter a code (as a security measure I guess). I don't have the owners manual since I got this car used.

Where can I find this code?

Comment: Try 1234, 9999, and any other usual suspects. In the case of my Mazda, it was one of these. Fortunately, the previous owners hadn't changed it. Failing that, yep, try the dealer or a car audio shop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is actually going to your local Mitsubishi dealer, make sure you have your registration/insurance with you.

Should be able to provide it free of charge.

Comment: Agree with going to the dealer. No real alternative that I am aware of, but doubtful that it will be done free of charge. If he was the original owner the dealer he bought it from _might_   do it at no charge.

Comment: This is what I figured the answer would be. I was just hoping there would be a DIY solution.

Comment: I wish there was man...

Comment: If they made  DIY procedure that would undo the purpose of having the security in first place.